# Accessing a private method from another class

Tags: c#

I have two repository classes (`RepositoryFactory` and `BaseRepository`) implementing different interfaces within the same project. The `BaseRepository` class has a private method that would be now needed also in the other class, with the same implementation.

Instead of duplicate the method in order to keep it private, I was thinking to a possible alternative, although so far I could not find a good solution since by definition a private method has scope only in its own class.

Using inheritance and change the method to "protected" would also not be an option, since the two classes are not linked semantically. I cannot use a public property giving back the result of the method since the return type is void.

Comment: They are in the same project; would `internal` not suffice?

Comment: So, you mean `RepositoryFactory` constructs various descendants of `BaseRepository` and you want factory to do something on the object via private method, before returning it?

Comment: If you want it to be accessable from other classes, you cannot use `private`.

Comment: You're looking for C++'s `friend` classes in C#? Sorry, doesn't exist. As Marc suggested, the closest alternative is `internal`.

Comment: It is hard to imagine that two classes with different purpose can have the same function implementation. They must have something in common. So why not just derive both classes from a new abstract base class then?

Comment: @CodyGray, you have some concept of friend classes, it's just they are so friends that they nest one inside the other... You could say they are really good friends! (see my answer)

Comment: @Joao: Hmmm, I don't have any friends like that. Anyway, I would refer to those as "nested classes", I don't really think that's the same thing as a friend class. Although it might be a solution in this case.

Comment: Thanks Marc and the others for the good hints. Internal would be a solution, but the target method should not be accessible outside of its class scope. If the method would have had a return value, I could have thought to introduce a public property in the same class and by that invoking it prior some conditions checks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not possible to do what you want in C#. The closest you can have is `internal`, which makes the member visible to an entire assembly. It might also be possible to make the two classes private and nested inside another class, but this isn't always appropriate.

Mads Torgersen, who works on C#, has this to say about it:

> I've seen a number of proposals trying to grapple with some notion of "class set accessibility." The complication of course is that, unlike existing accessibilities, there is not already a natural group (everyone, assembly, derived classes, single class) to tie it to, so even with another accessibility modifier you still also need syntax (or something) to define the group.
>
> There are several ways to slice it. I haven't seen a proposal that is obviously right, but I think the problem is relevant, and I will take this up with the design team.

([source](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/602150/a-practical-new-access-modifier-for-net-to-aid-in-developing-bullet-proof-code))

Comment: how about deriving them from the same baseclass that features the protected method? or have them implement the same interface and convert the mehod to a private extension method on that interface?

Comment: @mtijn You can't really make a private extension method like that. (if you come up with a way, please do post it!)

Comment: I don't know what I was thinking there, no indeed you cannot create extension methods like that, you could make an extension method with internal visibility, but that's an over-complicated way of doing the same thing Marc Gravell already suggested

Comment: @mtijn: as said, make the method protected and use inheritance would not be possible, since the two classes have different purposes. They would just need share the logic of that method.

Answer (score 20):

You can use reflection. Here's an example:

```
MethodInfo privMethod = objInstance.GetType().GetMethod("PrivateMethodName", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
privMethod.Invoke(objInstance, new object[] { methodParameters });
```

Comment: please note that this would drastically impact the performance if you use it quite often.

Answer (score 4):

You can, but it looks awkward. This takes advantage of nested classes being able to access private stuff from the containing class. However, **even if something is possible doesn't mean you should do it**. If you just change the modifier to `internal` you get the same behavior and since the two classes are coupled together then it makes sense to ship them in the same assembly, so internal modifier is the correct answer.

```
public class BaseRepository
{
    public sealed class RepositoryFactory
    {
        public static BaseRepository Create()
        {
            var repo = new BaseRepository();

            repo.MethodRequiredByRepositoryFactory();

            return repo;
        }
    }

    private void MethodRequiredByRepositoryFactory() { }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reference](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/75a48f/how-to-access-private-method-outside-the-class-in-C-Sharp/)

Possible by using reflection

1. Create a console application in Visual Studio.
2. Add 2 namespaces
   2.1. `System`
   2.2. `System.Reflection`
3. Now create a class and inside that class create one method that will be private as follows:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please finish your post? Step 3 seems incomplete.